# Object Oriented JavaScript: How would you go about this?

Tags: javascript, oop

As I've gotten to know JS better, I've moved from a procedural style to semi-OO (don't ask me what I mean by that: a mess basically!) but now I want to start using it properly. OO appeals to my coding-brain.

However, I'm trying to develop a library of school weeks, and I'm not sure how I'd best go about it.

If I was to simply use an array of weeks, they would look something like this:

```
    WeeksArray[36].StartDate = "2011-09-05";
    WeeksArray[36].EndDateSchool = "2011-09-09";
    WeeksArray[36].EndDateProper = "2011-09-11";
    WeeksArray[36].JSDate = new Date ( 2011, 8, 05 );
    WeeksArray[36].Type = "1";
    WeeksArray[36].Label = "Week 36: 5th Sept 2011";
```

- **Key**: Week number according to School Calendar
- **StartDate / EndDate**: MySQL-compatible date ranges
- **JSDate**: JS date object of start of week
- **Type**: school timetable, week 1 or 2
- **Label**: human-readable label indicating start of week

I would like this library to be accessible by other scripts, so that they can load an Array or Object containing all of the weeks in the school calendar. I'd imagine, for instance, one of my scripts producing a drop-down menu from this information, which displays "Week 36: 5th Sept 2011" and when clicked upon sends a request to my PHP script & SQL database then filters the information on screen accordingly. **NOTE: I don't need help with the implementation of the latter, it's just an example for context.**

I started coding as follows:

```
var LEAP = {}

LEAP.Schedule = {

    init: function() {
        this.setWeeks();
    }

    setWeeks: function() {
        var WeeksArray = [];
```

But the more I look at it, the less correct it feels!

Should I be creating "Week" objects, then a container for them which has a method to return all of the Week objects? I've been reading the OOP chapter in "Pro JavaScript Techniques" by John Resig, but truth be told I don't fully understand it. This feels like the right approach, but an Object within an Object is hurting my head.

The final outcome should be that I include this script on one of my pages, then can use something like `var WeeksArray = LEAP.Schedule.getWeeks();`, but even then I'm not sure that's realistic?

I'm rather confused...! :D Any help on the subject would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I think you could potentially have Weeks objects, but you shouldn't need to set so many of the properties directly. All of the date-related ones should be inferred from whatever Date you pass it.

Comment: I agree with Rob W's approach. OOP is good for simplifying complexity, but when the extent of your complexity is some calculations and hash lookups, no need to go overboard with making highly structured classes. You are basically just one step more abstract than built-in operators and language features, so just one class (or in this case, just one namespace even) is good enough to encapsulate the complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setWeeks: function(){
  var WeeksArray = []; //This variable is private, which is probably not your desired result.
}
```

^ That doesn't work, see comment.

I'd recommend something like this:
External file:

```
var LEAP = {};
LEAP.Schedule = function(){//init
  //all events which should only occur once should be called here
  //Create the initial objects, e.g.
  this.weeks = [];
  this.calculateWeeks();
}
LEAP.Schedule.protoype.calculateWeeks = function(){
  for (var i=0; i<52; i++){
    this.weeks.push(Math.random()); //For the sake of the example ;)
  }
}
LEAP.Schedule.prototype.getWeeks = function(){
  return this.weeks;
}
```

Main file:

```
var Scheduleobject = new LEAP.Schedule();
var weeks = Scheduleobject.getWeeks();
```

This feels like a very natural OOP approach, to me.
You can even change the LEAP.Schedule function such that it returns the Weeks array immediately, dependent on the situation.

### EDIT

An example of a week class:

```
LEAP.Schedule.week = function(n_year, n_month, n_day, n_week){
  //add code to validate the input
  //...
  //finished validating, processing:
  this.year = n_year;
  this.month = n_month;
  this.day = n_day;
  this.week = n_week;
}
LEAP.Schedule.week.protoype.getStartDate = function(){
  return year + "-" + pad(month) + "-" + pad(day);
}
//LEAP.Schedule.week.prototype.*Date are defined in a similar way
//The "EndDateSchool" and "EndDateProper" variables always follow the same pattern. Reduce the number of unnecessary variables by calculating these variables in the prototype function.
LEAP.Schedule.week.prototype.getLabel = function(){
  return "week" + this.week + ": " + this.day + (day==1||day==21||day==31?"st":day==2||day==22?"nd":day==3||day==23?"rd":"th") + " " + ["jan", "feb", "mar", "etc"][this.month-1] + " " + this.year;
}
function pad(n){return n>9?n:"0"+n}//a simple function to add a zero for your specific cases.
```

The week class can be called in this way:

```
var week = new Schedule.Week(2011, 8, 5, 36); //or this.Week(2011, 8, 5, 36) from the contex of the class.
var startDate = week.getStartDate(); //example`
```

Comment: Thanks for that Rob. What you've described here is the way I initially approached things (albeit wrongly ;) - an Array of weeks which can be returned via a function. You say that it's a very natural OOP approach, but would it not be "better" (not sure what other word to use there) to have a new Week object for every row in the array?

Comment: @dunc
See my updated answer. Don't overuse the OOP concept. It's discouraged to create several extra methods which do not serve a purpose outside the class.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my comment.

You might not ever need formal week objects. It might be enough to simply store which weeks are which type, and a formula for converting the number to a date. So your Calendar or Schedule object might have a property indicating the absolute day that week number 1 starts, and an array of week types in order. Then when getWeeks() is called, it can start at week 1 and build an array of the necessary weeks, which could be formal objects, or could simply be associative arrays:

```
weeks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.week_types.length; i++){
    weeks[i] = {
    "StartDate": this.get_start_date(i),
    "JSDate": this.get_js_date(i),
    ..., //The rest of the properties
    "type": this.week_types[i],
    "Label": this.get_label(i)
}
```

Hopefully that starts you on the right track, I'm happy to help if I can provide further clarification.

Comment: Thanks Alec. I will indeed bear this in mind - it's what I wanted to do originally but for clarity of this post decided to go with a manually-inputted array.

Comment: I often prefer using plain objects, but in this case, a Week object may be a better choice. What happens in the code proposed by Alec Munro? A loop creates a new object, executing several functions immediately, in order to calculate values which may never be used. Also, when the week algorithm changes, the object has to be recreated again.

If you use a week object, some primitive values are set, which can be used when the inherited (prototype) functions are called.

Comment: Rob is correct that mine is a very inefficient solution as written. That might not matter for your implementation but you could always initialize the weeks when the Schedule is created. Or, as I think Rob is suggesting, you could move the computation functions (get_x()) to a Week class, and call them when you actually need those values, rather than having them as properties on the Week, or an anonymous object.